# Get expanded group view of an ExpandableListView using onGroupExpand

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I'm using an [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html#setOnGroupExpandListener%28android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener%29) and I'm unsuccessfully trying to move an image when expanding a group (the image being part of the group view).

Here is my code :

```
my_list_view.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Group " + my_list_view.getGroupId(groupPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Basically my problem is : how can I access the expanded Group view, when the only variable I can use is groupPosition?

Any you-should-create-a-custom-adapter-like response won't be accepted. I already tried that and it doesn't work for my issue. What I need is to listen the onGroupExpand event.

Comment: Really, I don't how to do that. I guess the function I should use is `getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` but the thing is that I only have the `groupPosition`. I guess `isExpanded` should be set to true, but what about `convertView` and `parent`???

Comment: have you got any solution?

Comment: Check this answer. It work with me (http://stackoverflow.com/a/22912225/5621162)

Answer (score 11):

What I eventually did is using the `boolean isExpanded` you get for free in `getGroupView` when you make a custom adapter. I was able to make things work the way I wanted with that, instead of doing it in the activity. If you save the context you get in the constructor, you can use that to get resources.

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  if (isExpanded) {
    mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow)
    doSomething();
  }
  else {
    doSomethingElse();
  }
}
```

That's a lot easier than my other answer (which was a bit buggy anyway), so forget about that one :)

Comment: Thanks. I already tried this solution some time ago and it is buggy + it doesn't make sense to change the group view in this class. It should be inside the onGroupExpand event.